# How to transfer MC resource packs created on Windows 10 to SWITCH/XBOX

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-one, nintendo-switch, minecraft-resource-packs

I created some resource packs on Windows 10 edition.
Is there any way I can transfer the pack over to my Xbox/switch and use it
there?
I would prefer a way to do it without downloading additional UN-trustworthy software on my PC, I know there is a simple way to do it, I just cant find it

Comment: So you say you know there's a simple way to do it. Just curious but, how do you know this? Last I heard those resource packs were DLC you had to buy.

Comment: Well, no. i'm talking about resources i created, not the DLC.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. You say you *know* there is a simple way to do it, but how do you know it's even possible to upload custom resource packs *at all*?

Comment: ha, no im sorry, im just assuming im stupid and there's probably an easy way to do it. although im not sure, that's why im here. but i know i did create a resource pack on windows 10

Answer (score 3):

On the Switch and Xbox, there's only one official way.

On the Nintendo Switch and Xbox ***Bedrock Edition***, you can use a resource pack on a Realm if you install the Resource pack onto the Realm on a non-console device (if you install the resource pack onto the Realm from Windows 10 edition or the Pocket Edition.) When you join the Realm on the Switch/Xbox, they will be installed and used on the Realm, but once you leave, they will be automatically removed from the device.

If you wanted to permanently install it (until you feel like removing it, of course), there's one way to do it on the Switch. However, that will void your warranty and can possibly brick/corrupt your system. This will require you to install Homebrew on to it, which you can read here:

http://www.mcbedrock.com/showthread.php?786-How-to-get-Custom-resource-packs-on-Switch-Bedrock

On the Xbox, you'd need to do some more research as to how to hack it (which I'm sure will also void your warranty and risk corrupting your system as well.) If you really want to take the risk, I'd recommend reading the guides all the way, possibly with help from an experienced user. IMO if you just want to do it to install resource packs, it's not worth the risk.

Comment: I think its fair to assume that if you find a way to run code that did not pass through an approval by Microsoft on Xbox you are doing some stuff that will void your warranty. I'm surprised the realms thing works, to be honest.